# how to make superlu in windows

Tags: c++, windows, makefile

I have downloaded armadillo 6.5. it needs `superLU(4.3)` library to solve sparse matrix system of equations.

I have downloaded `superlu` from [here](http://crd-legacy.lbl.gov/~xiaoye/SuperLU/)  but when i want to make it in windows, it gives:

```
( cd SRC; make )
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, ( cd SRC; make ), ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
Makefile:36: recipe for target 'superlulib' failed
make: *** [superlulib] Error 2
```

if i cd to `SRC` directory manually and do `make` in there, a lot of `*.o` file is created but again i get this error:

```
ar cr /Codes/SuperLU/SuperLU_4.3/lib/libsuperlu_4.3.a \
        sgssv.o sgssvx.o ssp_blas2.o ssp_blas3.o sgscon.o slangs.o sgsequ.o slaqgs.o spivotgrowth.o sgsrfs.o sgstrf.o sgstrs.o scopy_to_ucol.o ssnode_dfs.o ssnode_bmod.o spanel_dfs.o sp
anel_bmod.o sreadhb.o sreadrb.o sreadtriple.o scolumn_dfs.o scolumn_bmod.o spivotL.o spruneL.o smemory.o sutil.o smyblas2.o sgsisx.o sgsitrf.o sldperm.o ilu_sdrop_row.o ilu_ssnode_dfs.o
 ilu_scolumn_dfs.o ilu_spanel_dfs.o ilu_scopy_to_ucol.o ilu_spivotL.o sdiagonal.o superlu_timer.o util.o memory.o get_perm_c.o mmd.o sp_coletree.o sp_preorder.o sp_ienv.o relax_snode.o
heap_relax_snode.o colamd.o ilu_relax_snode.o ilu_heap_relax_snode.o mark_relax.o mc64ad.o qselect.o lsame.o xerbla.o slacon.o  slamch.o
ar: /Codes/SuperLU/SuperLU_4.3/lib/libsuperlu_4.3.a: No such file or directory
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'single' failed
make: *** [single] Error 1
```

i almost have no experience with "make" and "superlu". how can i make superlu in windows? is there any precompiled superlu library available for windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems that makefile is written for linux systems.
I could do three thing:

1. follow the instructions on superLU [FAQ page](http://crd-legacy.lbl.gov/~xiaoye/SuperLU/faq.html#windows):

> This was tested in MS Visual Studio. However the configuration highly
>   depends on which compiler you using. Normally there is an IDE
>   (Integrated Development Environment) editor associated with your
>   compiler. You can do it in two steps:
>
> Step I: Create SuperLU library file
>           Create a new project, then include all the .c and .h files in SRC directory (they can be put in two folders of the IDE).
>           Change the property of the project to make the output as Library file .lib (not .exe or .dll file).
>           Compile the project to produce the library file, e.g. superlu.lib. (after you successfully compile it, you can build a
>   release version without the debug information).
>
> Step II: Build your own application Create a new project with your own
>   source files which call the SuperLU routines.Add the SRC directory and
>   the directory where superlu.lib is located to the include path and
>   library searching path respectively.
>           Add superlu.lib as the link optional library.
>           Compile your own .dll or .exe file. Then you are done.
>
> If you are using a compiler with command line only, you have to play
>   with the makefile or -I -L -O -c options. As SuperLU calls BLAS
>   routines but BLAS is not a native library of MS Visual Studio, you
>   have to build your own BLAS library in the similar way as SuperLU
>   library. The SuperLU distribution includes a C version of BLAS in
>   SuperLU/CBLAS directory. This version is only functional but not fast.
>   For speed, it's better to use vendor-supplied BLAS (e.g., Intel MKL)
>   or public domain versions (e.g., ATLAS, or Goto BLAS).

i could not do it right.

2. rewrite the whole makefile for windows(i couldn't do it either because i dont know how to write a makefile)

**And finally** the working solution(for me):

3. I found a repo in github that added superLU build support for windows!
   you can find it [here](https://github.com/pbosetti/SuperLU)

it has a Visual Studio(2010) solution file that builds the library and gives a `lib` file.

Comment: i also was able to compile and use library using first method.(created a code blocks static library project, added all files in src and cblas directory, and just built them into a .a library file)